# How to encyrpt a message using someone's SSL smime.p7s file

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography

I need to send a private key file to someone (a trusted sysadmin) securely. I suggested a couple options, but he replied as follows:

> Hi, I don't have neither LastPass nor GnuPGP but I'm using ssl
>   certificates - this message is signed with such so you will be able to
>   send a message to me and encrypt it with my public key.

I used openssl to obtain his certificate:

```
openssl pkcs7 -in smime.p7s -inform DER -print_certs
```

The certificate is issued by:

```
issuer=/O=Root CA/OU=http://www.cacert.org/CN=CA Cert Signing Authority/emailAddress=support@cacert.org
```

(Firefox doesn't have a root certificate from cacert.org.)

Now, how do I encrypt the key file I wish to send to him? I prefer to use a command line tool available in Ubuntu.

@lgeorget:

```
$ openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -outform PEM -in smime.p7s -out smime.pem
$ openssl smime -encrypt -text -in /home/myuser/.ssh/mykeyfile smime.pem 
unable to load certificate
139709295335072:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:696:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

and

```
$ openssl pkcs7 -in smime.p7s -inform DER -print_certs
subject=/CN=Wojciech Kapcia/emailAddress=someone@example.com/emailAddress=someone@example.com
issuer=/O=Root CA/OU=http://www.cacert.org/CN=CA Cert Signing Authority/emailAddress=support@cacert.org
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFzjCCA7agAwIBAgIDDR9oMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMHkxEDAOBgNVBAoTB1Jv
b3QgQ0ExHjAcBgNVBAsTFWh0dHA6Ly93d3cuY2FjZXJ0Lm9yZzEiMCAGA1UEAxMZ
dEBjYWNlcnQub3JnMB4XDTEzMDQxODA3NDEzNFoXDTE1MDQxODA3NDEzNFowcDEY
MBYGA1UEAxMPV29qY2llY2ggS2FwY2lhMSkwJwYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhp3b2pjaWVj
[snip]
N1lNLq5jrGhqMzA2ge57cW2eDgCL941kMmIPDUyx+pKAYj1I7IibN3wcP1orOys3
amWMrFRa30LBu6jPYy2TeeoQetKnabefMNE3Jv81gn41mPOs3ToPXEUmYU18VZ75
Efd/qu4SV/3SMdySSNmPAVQdXYAxBEXoN5b5FpUW7KeZnjoX4fkEUPeBnNwcptTC
d1w=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Could you give the output of `openssl pkcs7 -in smime.p7s -inform DER -print_certs` ?

Comment: @lgeorget - updated with this output. thanks

Comment: Okay so the problem is just the format. You should cut the first two lines and put the rest in a file called cert.pem or something like that. (It has already been converted to PEM when you did print_certs because DER is a binary unprintable format). The problem with OpenSSL is that it expects that the file begins with ----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
openssl smime -encrypt -text -in <file> smime.p7s
```

where `<file>` is the file you want to encrypt. If the file `smime.p7s` is in DER format instead of PEM, you will have to convert it with :

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -outform PEM -in smime.p7s -out smime.pem
```

You obtain a file you can send to your sysadmin. If you are brave enough you can remove `-text` and play with the option `-to`, `-subject`, etc. to get a valid email file you can directly send to a SMTP server.

If the root certificate of the certificate you use to encrypt is not recognized by your operating system but YOU trust it, you can add it to the certificate base.

```
cp smime.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/certificate.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

The certificate must have the `.crt` extension. Details [here](http://blog.donovan-jimenez.com/2011/03/adding-new-trusted-certificate-on.html).

Comment: I'm getting an error: Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE. See update in my question for more details. Thanks

Comment: If you trust the certificate that signs this certificate, then you can import it as a trusted certificate in your operating system. Just give me a minute to remember how you can do that.

Comment: @MountainX I edited :-).

Comment: Actually your error might be caused by a wrong format. Are you sure it's PEM?

Comment: The root certificate is available here: http://www.cacert.org/index.php?id=3 Should I not download it from there and install that one in my OS instead of the method you gave?

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's the right method if the CA is public. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, extracting the cert FROM the pkcs7 with -print_certs is correct, and if you want to trust the recipient's root use the one from cacert.org, not the cert from the pkcs7.

Some explanations/notes:

The extra lines before the cert block are no problem. openssl allows 'comment' text in PEM files 
before the '-----BEGIN' line (and after '-----END') although this is nonstandard 
and *other* programs often don't.

The error message about 'TRUSTED CERTIFICATE' is somewhat misleading. openssl actually 
allows two variants in a certificate PEM file: '[X.509] CERTIFICATE' and 'TRUSTED CERTIFICATE'. 
The former is standard, the latter is used only within openssl and then only rarely. 
openssl looks for them in that order, so if it doesn't find either the error message says 
TRUSTED not found. This format allows certain trust attributes in the cert file, and is 
different from the presence of the cert in openssl's trust store directory (or file).

`openssl sime -encrypt` does NOT check that the recipient cert validates against the trust store, although maybe it should.
If there's any possibility the p7s/cert you received was tampered or forged,
you should manually `openssl verify` the cert before using it, because if that cert actually 
has a bad guy's key instead of the good guy's, your data can be decrypted by the bad guy.